# JQuery UI selectmenu not styling

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, select-menu

Bit of a daft question but I've downloaded the JqueryUI selectmenu widget and it isn't working even though Firebug shows the relevant CSS and JavaScript files being loaded.

**Script on page**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#brand_color').selectmenu({style:'popup'});
</script>
```

**Generated form markup**:

```
<label for="brand_color">Color</label><br />
<select id="brand_color" name="brand[color]">
   <option value="red">red</option>
   <option value="green">green</option>
   <option value="blue">blue</option>
   <option value="black">black</option>
</select><br />
```

**Rails form code**:

```
<%= f.label :color %><br />
<%= f.select(:color, Brand::COLORS) %><br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi It definitely has to do with including all the required scripts.  It is a little hard to tell exactly what you need from [this demo](http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/demos/selectmenu/default.html), but I made sure to include all the same scripts and made an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/8WWMT/7/

here are all the scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js"></script>
<script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/demos/demos.css">​
```

Also you have to make sure that you JS is called after your HTML elements are rendered.  You can either do this by positioning your `<script>` tag after you HTML elements, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/8WWMT/9/).  Or by enclosing the JS inside the `$(function(){});`, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#brand_color').selectmenu({style:'popup'});
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8WWMT/10/

notice how the styling does not work if you put the script part above the HTML elements without using the `$(function(){});` (ready function): http://jsfiddle.net/8WWMT/11/

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the problem. All assets are included and loaded: http://i.imgur.com/zlyKq.png and http://i.imgur.com/vTQtR.png

Comment: you have to make sure the that javascript `$('#brand_color').selectmenu({style:'popup'});` is called after the HTML elements are rendered... see my update.

Comment: All fiddles of the answer - http://jsfiddle.net/8WWMT/7/, http://jsfiddle.net/8WWMT/9/,  http://jsfiddle.net/8WWMT/10/ and http://jsfiddle.net/8WWMT/11/ show the "non-styled" select menu. Any idea what is wrong? Obviously the answer itself cannot show it is working (at least at this moment which is 10 years after original post :) )